How can a string literal be converted into a SyntaxTree?
While watching WWDC, I learned that returning a string literal directly like "URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/kr")" allows ExprSyntax to automatically create and return a SyntaxTree. However, I couldn’t find the code in the SwiftSyntax library that makes this possible.
Upon further investigation, it seems that the Syntax types that conform to the SyntaxExpressibleByStringInterpolation protocol make this possible. Many Syntax types in SwiftSyntaxBuilder conform to this protocol, as shown in the example below:
extension DeclSyntax: SyntaxExpressibleByStringInterpolation {}

If my understanding is correct, when passing a string literal to a Syntax type, the following initializer should be executed, right?
extension SyntaxExpressibleByStringInterpolation {
  public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
    var interpolation = SyntaxStringInterpolation()
    interpolation.appendLiteral(value)
    self.init(stringInterpolation: interpolation)
  }
}

Another thing I’m curious about is when returning an array of string literals like
["var number: Int", "init(number: Int) { ... }"]

which initializer is being called? How is this possible? I really can't find it.
thx!

You pretty much found all the answers yourself. Yes, init(stringLiteral) is called. Why would an array of string literals be different?

@Sweeper The answer is not far off. thanks!
